# routing with two network interfaces (Keycloak/nextcloud/Discourse/…) and http proxy

Tags: docker, networking, iptables, http-proxy, network-interface

I want to host a couple of (dockerized) web applications (e.g. [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/), [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) and [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/)). The servers I have to use have two network interfaces: `eth1` and `eth0`.

`eth1` is the production interface – this is where user's requests reach the server & applications. Easy enough.

`eth0` is the administration interface – this is what I use to update packages/download docker images/etc. All traffic has to go trough a http-proxy (I think it's [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)). Most of the times setting the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable is enough to get it to work.

*However*, the web-applications sometimes need to use `eth0` as well. For example, if a cron triggers some updates or emails. How do I tell my web applications to use `eth0` and the proxy-server? Some Applications do not support proxies natively, so I figure I need to configure some clever networking on my RHEL8? Can I solve my issue with docker-daemon settings?

Can you point me in a direction? What do I have to look into? Could ip-tables solve my issue?

Thanks a lot! I am pretty new to this stuff and don't really know where to start—any hint is appreciated!